# date-fns-timezone Giving Wrong Result?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, datetime, date-fns

Right now it's Sunday Aug 30, 2020 5:20pm PST.

If I run this:

```
import {formatToTimeZone } from 'date-fns-timezone';
const dateNow = new Date();
const timeFormattedForUserTimezone = formatToTimeZone(dateNow, 'h:mm A z, MMM do, YYYY', {timeZone:'Europe/Berlin'})
```

...I get this in `timeFormattedForUserTimezone`:

> 2:20 AM CEST, Aug 1st, 2020

Google disagrees and tells me the time in Berlin is:

> 2:23 AM August 31, 2020

...i.e. Aug 31st rather than Aug 1st.

What am I missing?

Comment: It's definitely the 31st Aug in Berlin right now ;) Use `h:mm A z, MMM Do, YYYY` which is `Do` according to the docs here: https://github.com/prantlf/date-fns-timezone/blob/master/docs/API.md#formattotimezone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your time string is `'h:mm A z, MMM do, YYYY'` which uses `do` which is `Day of week`.

Use `'h:mm A z, MMM Do, YYYY'` instead (Note the upper case `D` in `Do` which stands for `Day of month`).

Docs here: https://github.com/prantlf/date-fns-timezone/blob/master/docs/API.md#formattotimezone

So your code becomes:

```
import {formatToTimeZone } from 'date-fns-timezone';
const dateNow = new Date();
const timeFormattedForUserTimezone = formatToTimeZone(dateNow, 'h:mm A z, MMM Do, YYYY', {timeZone:'Europe/Berlin'})
```